# Does SO, SF, MSO, and SU make enough support $$$ from ads?

Tags: discussion, advertising, business-model

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is Stack Overflow's business model?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79435/what-is-stack-overflows-business-model)

I was curious if the ad support has continued to bring in enough $$$ to support the SO,SF, MSO, and SU websites?  This is a user site, but servers and bandwidth costs money. They must be doing ok since the websites continue to grow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, but it's a whole lot of work to make that happen... both on the ad side and the site development side.

jjnguy already mentioned that there's three full-time on the development side. You may be surprised to know that there are 4 full-time staff on the ad side... and growing!

Comment: Why don't you change your Gravatar?

Comment: I see you have fixed it already.

Answer (score 5):

I also hear that some yacht companies are planning to bring huge sponsorship to the next StackExchange site - for boat programming questions.

Comment: Are you ever going to let that boat programming question go? It's getting kind of old.

Comment: @Kyle - I have a need for the boat-programming tag and site.  I program on a boat.  It is relevant to me and I intend to get the hosted stack exchange for it.  I figure the ads I get from generator companies, boat manufacturers and th elike will pay for the hosting fees.

Comment: Have you tried posting your own question? If you have a legitimate need it might go over better than a joke question.

Comment: I only used the tag in my own questions - there was a flurry of activity of that use after some rabid editors discovered the tags (which had existed on my questions for over a week without the world ending)

Comment: if you really program on a boat, post pictures of you programming on the boat.. preferably holding a "meta.stackoverflow.com" sign..

Comment: Nice.  The only problem is, the post would get deleted...  I guess it can go on a website.  Stay tuned.

Comment: sure -- add it to your profile! I want a copy of today's newspaper, and the words "meta.stackoverflow.com" printed on that newspaper, though.. :)

Answer (score 3):

It's not just ad support: At this moment, there are 84 jobs on the [job board](http://jobs.stackoverflow.com/). A job posting is 350 bucks for 21 days, so if 80 is average (they have a refund policy), that's $42000 per month (which is probably shared with joelonsoftware, but still).

I'd take a piece of that cake in no time.

Answer (score 2):

Jeff [keeps hiring](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/welcome-stack-overflow-valued-associate-00003/) [full time developers](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/welcome-stack-overflow-valued-associate-00002/), so I assume they are getting by just fine for now at least.

Comment: Either that or he's become an accomplished bank robber.

Comment: Hmmm. I just heard on the radio that Iowa is on pace to have a record number of bank robberies this year and I know that Jeff has family in Iowa.  I wonder...

Comment: Ha, no one would suspect a high profile developer living in California to be a bank robber...Good cover Jeff!

Answer (score 1):

Balpha has the right answer; ad revenue is trivial, job advertisement revenue is essential.

In developing a business plan for my proposed stack exchange, I did some homework on how much ad revenue I could expect.  The calculation is outlined well [here](http://www.sanjaydhingra.com/formula-for-calculating-google-adsense-revenue/).  For my assumptions, job advertising was essential to cover my costs.  Google adsense (and Amazon affiliate) revenue wasn't sufficient.

Comment: It's all about the audience, and the SO audience is among the best.

Try putting ads in front of the YouTube/FaceBook crowd... good luck making a living off of that.