# Will Stack Overflow ask for money?

Tags: discussion, sign-up

I think this is the most programmer-friendly website in the world.

Will Stack Overflow ask for a credit card one day, like Experts-Exchange?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16378/add-a-paypal-link-to-accept-donations

Comment: What a curious emphasis.

Comment: StackOverflow doesn't ask for money; neither performs any kind of surgeries nor has a hyphen in its name. SO is AWESOME :)

Comment: However, according to the awesomeness of the site, and the fact it *forces* you to come back and spend time, I guess it asks for your employer's money.

Comment: Gnoupi: I can't see anyone **force** people to come back.

Comment: @Mehrdad: You haven't seen it...but it happens.  Don't make the men in trenchcoats mad.

Comment: I have an uneasy feeling about sites where I can't see a revenue flow.  On the other hand, I've seen sufficient ads in the right margin to make me confident about SO.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This is not a duplicate of donations IMO.

No, we will never convert to a for-pay website, requiring users to pay for continued access.

I realize "never" is a long time, but it should not happen while I have a say in the matter.

Comment: Hestonesque translation: "You have to put your money into my cold, dead hands"

Comment: Yay! Now it's something different. Dude!!!