# How does Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Overflow, etc. make money?

Tags: discussion, advertising, business-model

How do Stack Overflow and the rest of Stack Exchange sites stay up?

Someone has got to pay for the infrastructure and people's wages. So how do these sites make money?  Is it purely through advertising?

*(I'm not looking to copy it! :) I'm just amazed that such a great system works **for free!**)*

Comment: You don't think that Jon Skeet really got that rep without a little payola, do you?

Comment: Seriously - why vote a question down that asks a perfectly reasonable question?

Comment: @Mark: If A then B if-and-only-if if not B then not A. If only perfectly reasonable questions do not get downvotes, the fact that you're getting downvotes implies your question is not perfectly reasonable. Programmers are supposed to be good at logic.

Comment: I use FF, I see adds.  Those two aren't mutually exclusive.

Comment: Justin - I said FF + adblock.
The Proposer - I think my question is reasonable because it is a genuine question about the policy of this site. And I find your response unnecessarily rude. And illogical - you're using a circular argument: "it is because it is".  That's funny.

Comment: -1...may God have mercy on your soul.

Comment: I find the question perfectly fine, although it may well be a duplicate.

Comment: @Mark: how is it that you find it acceptable to announce that you are circumventing a site's revenue stream (by using Adblock)?

Comment: This is pretty much the same question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8208/does-so-sf-mso-and-su-make-enough-support-from-ads -- but considering it's almost a year old, and lots of things have happened since then, I don't know if this should really be closed because of that.

Comment: Hi Ether - I didn't say I used Adblock, I said it was possible.

Comment: Thanks to the responders so far, the people who voted up my question so that it is no longer on -2, and especially the moderators for removing an offensive comment. This comment is not part of the question - I just wanted to say thanks.

Comment: @Mark it wasn't necessarily the moderators who removed the comments, it could have been the author himself. While I felt the downvotes to this question unjustified, in general, downvotes are viewed as an expression of disagreement on Meta. A perfectly fine proposal can attract a lot of downvotes if people simply don't agree with it. They shouldn't be taken too seriously here.

Comment: Sigh... it is starting again. If you're voting down please say why - I'm still trying to learn.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Down with the 30 day waiting

Comment: Actually, it's possible that enough people flagged the comments as offensive that they were deleted that way. I know one comment disappeared right after I flagged it. @Down

Comment: @mmyers - My thanks for you flagging it as well.

Comment: @mmyers yeah. I was somehow hoping Welbog had removed them himself, but I may have been wrong. Anyway....

Comment: Related: [What is Stack Overflow's business model?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79435/what-is-stack-overflows-business-model)

Comment: Bit late to the party, but let me have a say: I'm *forced* to "block" ads even on SE. This is because I'm using no ad blocker at all (hah! crude logic!), but NoScript. And ads on here are all hosted on QuantServe. And I am not allowing QS. So supposing the ads server would have a more unique, less overused name (mind you, QS is what all and sundry use to display their ads) I'd *surely* allow it. But my problem is that I would to have to allow QS for all sites. Wish there was an option like "when SE displays ads using QS, display them, otherwise block them". :)

Answer (score 46):

[Ads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advertising), [jobs listings](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/Jobs), [careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/).  Do a search for [money](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=money) on meta and you'll see lots of relevant questions.

Comment: The first link is broken.

Comment: First link is still broken. There's a reason we don't just post links.

Comment: First link is still broken in 2017, no wonder we don't just post links.

Comment: The link may be broken, but it wasn't really essential to the answer.  It was originally just a link to a question about a particular ad that everyone seemed to hate that was asked at about the same time as this one.  I suppose I update it to point at the [advertising] tag.

Comment: First link is back up!  In case it ever goes down again, here's the earliest archived image of it to prove @Zoredache correct. :) https://web.archive.org/web/20140426141741/http://meta.stackexchange.com:80/questions/tagged/advertising

Answer (score 4):

People will pay money to have their advertisements on popular websites. The amount of traffic in the stacks probably makes the advertisement expense relatively expensive. Its the same reason some games are free.

I'm sure there are many other little bits of money coming in/out, but personally I think advertisements is the biggest source of revenue for a free website like this

Comment: Advertisements ??? I dont see many adds on this site. I believe, stackoverflow works with recruiters to help get good people and get paid by them.

Comment: They gets lot of traffic through google , if you searched at google with any programming related problem this site will popup on the first page top five result. There are tremendous resources on this site and many coding experts.

Comment: @MansoorShaikh you probably have adblock

Comment: @crl even with adblock off, I rarely see more than 2 or 3 ads a month