# From where does the Stack Exchange network get its money to serve all these visitors?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Overflow, etc. make money?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55790/how-does-stack-overflow-meta-stack-overflow-etc-make-money)

There is this BIG network: Unix, Super User, Android, etc. There have to be big [?] servers behind these websites that are hosted at XY place. This costs money. **Where do the Stack Exchange guys get all the money for this? From donations? I can't see any ads on the websites!**

I'm just asking, because it's an important thing in the future to be capable of serving all the growing interest in these kinds of websites! For example, Wikipedia also advertised that it needs donations and whooosh, donations came!

Comment: If you don't see any ads, it's a sign of SE doing non-intrusive advertising right. Either that or you're not looking hard enough.

Comment: I don't think the servers are as big as you think they are. In fact, I'm pretty sure that the trilogy (Stack Overflow, Server Fault, Super User) gets more traffic than all of the other Stack Exchange sites put together. Which is not to say that it doesn't cost money to run, but it's not Google or Facebook.

Comment: @Aarobot: I would even suppose that Stack Overflow alone gets more traffic than the rest together.

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann: yes, by far. This was stated by Jeff Atwood in the Stack Exchange podcast, [episode 24 (#107 in the old numbering scheme)](http://www.podtrac.com/pts/redirect.mp3/feeds.soundcloud.com/stream/26443821-stack-exchange-stack-exchange-podcast-24.mp3) (MP3 format, 66 MB).

Answer (score 5):

90% of SE traffic comes from non-users. They see commercial banners .

Comment: I remember some discussion about this on the podcast: http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/shows/detail4211.html

Answer (score 5):

Stack Exchange, Inc. is backed by [venture capital.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/announcing-our-series-a/)

Comment: +1 that's also my impression.  Venture capital + custom ads + job board.

Comment: +1 and also interesting to read: http://techcrunch.com/2011/03/09/founder-stories-stack-exchange-spolsky-vc/